# How can I get rid of javascript-common errors when installing packages?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have been getting this error when installing packages on a development LAMP, Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
  javascript-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The package install seems to work, but the error concerns me. It has happened when installing ntp, re-installing php5, installing n98-magerun, basically all the time.

I never saw this error when initially setting up the server, but it's everywhere I look nowadays.

Any idea on what is causing this, and possibly a good fix?

Comment: Have you tried the solution that pops up when you do a google search for your exact error message?

Comment: The uninstall? I have. At some point in the install process it came back though. Also, I think I want javascript-common, unless there is a replacement.